# Create an UIImage out of a website's URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata, nsurl

```
NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"stackoverflow.com"];
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgURL];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
```

Using with these codes, is it possible to create an UIImage out of a website's URL? Sorry if the question is not clear, what I mean is to screenshot the whole webpage to produce an UIImage. Can I do that with these?

Comment: You mean website's "screenshot"? No you can't do this, use WKWebView to render website, then you can make image from that render.

Comment: you can not create image from url , yeah but you can load image from url if you have url of image(not website).

Comment: @Igor yes, I'm using WKWebView and I tried rendering it using `renderInContext:` and `drawViewHierarchyInRect: afterScreenUpdates:` but I'm not getting the image I desire.

Comment: It's a lot of examples in the internet:
http://atmarkplant.com/wkwebview-screenshots/
or just google "WKWebView to uiimage"

Comment: @Igor I've also used that but just a part of the webpage is rendered to the UIImage and most of UIImage is just white. [link](http://i.imgur.com/pimZNgx.png) here's what I'm talking about

Answer (score 0):

From this link. yes u can.

```
NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg
"];
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgURL];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
```

If u need to load images without freezing the app, and also to implement thumbnail and cache,

Try SDWebImage framework

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

**Sample Code**

```
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Get each url from array and set it here using indexpath.row"]
                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

**Screenshot**

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
[self.myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *imageView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView, 1.0 ); //you can use PNG too
```

Comment: i think so he is asking for making thumbnail of URL.Not downloading the image

Comment: the questioner asked to create the thumb image for the URL bro, please update/customize your answer

Comment: @DHEERAJ I tried your Screenshot solution but I'm not getting the image I desire. It only gives me blank/white image.